# Elementor plugin not working on localhost

Tags: wordpress

I am new to wordpress and start building my website using elementor, I am using localhost but elementor is not working.

Comment: check your console. may be some error in javascript

Comment: "not working" is always totally unclear. What happens / what did you try to fix it / are there any errors...

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Answer (score 2):

If you are experiencing problems using Elementor, please try to follow these steps:

- Make sure your server's PHP version is above 5.4
- Make sure you are using the most updated versions of Elementor, WordPress & your theme.
- Deactivate all your plugins besides Elementor (and Elementor Pro). If this solves the problem, gradually activate your plugins one by one, until you spot the problematic plugin.
- If you have a caching plugin, make sure you deactivate it, or even better – purge the cache.
- Change your WordPress theme to WordPress TwentySixteen (or other default WordPress theme).
- On your WordPress root folder, edit the wp-config.php and set the value of WP-DEBUG to true.
- Ask in the Elementors community Facebook group & forum
- Under Elementor > Settings > Advanced switch editor loader method on